# Devise won't create user, redirects back to registration page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Normally, Devise works perfectly when I add new users. Right now, I'm unable to figure out why this problem is occurring since there really isn't much to tell from the server console. I'm slugging the username with friendly_id btw. I have a second users_controller outside of devise that I created for profiles. I doubt that it's the reason Devise doesn't work since it isn't using it as a sub-class.

Here is the contents of my user.rb

```
validates :username, :presence => true, :uniqueness => {:case_sensitive => false }
  validate :validate_username
  validates_uniqueness_of :username, :email
  validates_presence_of :email, :username
  validates :username,
            :presence => true,
            :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false },
            :format => { with: /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/ },
            :length => { in: 4..20 }
  validate :password_complexity
 => true

  #Changes Devise method to accept both email and username for the login method.
  def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    if login = conditions.delete(:login)
      where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
    else
      if conditions[:username].nil?
        where(conditions).first
      else
        where(username: conditions[:username]).first
      end
    end
  end

  #Checks if Password format is correct
  def password_complexity
    if password.present? && !password.match(/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d). /)
      errors.add :password, "must include at least one lowercase letter, one uppercase letter, and one number"
    end
  end

  #Checks if username exist in the database
  def validate_username
    if User.where(email: username).exists?
      errors.add(:username, :invalid)
    end
  end
```

Users_Controller.rb (Just in case you find something that might be the cause of the Devise outage)

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update]

  def index
    @users = User.friendly.all.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 45)
  end

  def show
    @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @posts = @user.posts.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
  end

  def edit
    @user.build_profile if @user.profile.nil?
  end


  def update
    if @user.update(user_params, id: id)
      redirect_to user_profile_path(@user)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def follow
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    current_user.follow(@user)
    redirect_to :back
  end

  private

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, profile_attributes: [:id, :name, :birthday, :sex, :tel, :address, :tagline, :introduction, :avatar])
  end
end
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  helper_method :current_user_subscribed?

  def current_user_subscribed?
    user_signed_in? && current_user.subscribed?
  end

  private

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    home_path(resource)
  end

  def after_update_path_for(resource)
    home_path(resource)
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    hub_index_path(resource)
  end

  protected
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :avatar) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:login, :username, :email, :password, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :current_password, :avatar) }
  end

end
```

Here is the server response

```
Started GET "/users/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-26 19:22:55 -0500
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
  Rendered users/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (89.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 626ms (Views: 605.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/users/sign_up?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=6KXAPkbVLgpCOV1mu6j9yHw%2Bif2PkrecoPLqFP08yT644658a74HyN1BAmAUXQ93WPjfSJEwVX6NN5EyfFxyoQ%3D%3D&user%5Busername%5D=Bigjohn&user%5Bavatar%5D=&user%5Bemail%5D=john1002%40hotmail.com&user%5Bpassword%5D=[FILTERED]&user%5Bpassword_confirmation%5D=[FILTERED]&commit=Sign+up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-26 19:27:11 -0500
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"âœ“", "authenticity_token"=>"6KXAPkbVLgpCOV1mu6j9yHw+if2PkrecoPLqFP08yT644658a74HyN1BAmAUXQ93WPjfSJEwVX6NN5EyfFxyoQ==", "user"=>{"username"=>"Bigjohn", "avatar"=>"", "email"=>"john1002@hotmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
  Rendered users/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (14.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 508ms (Views: 507.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Here is the new.html.erb form for users

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form class="form-horizontal sign-up-form-padding">
      <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: {multipart: true }) do |f| %>
          <%= f.error_notification %>
          <div class="col-md-6 registration-form-col-centered">
            <div class="sign-up-label">
              <h1>Register</h1>
            </div>
            <fieldset class="form-group">
              <label style="font-weight: bold;">Username</label>
              <div class="form-control">
                <%= f.input :username, label: false %>
              </div>
              <small class="text-muted">Choose a cool username for your profile</small>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="form-group">
              <label style="font-weight: bold">Upload an Avatar Photo</label>

              <div class="form-control">
                <%= f.file_field :avatar, required: false %>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="form-group">
              <label style="font-weight: bold">Email</label>

              <div class="form-control">
                <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true, label: false %>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label style="font-weight: bold">Password</label>

              <div class="form-control">
                <%= f.input :password, required: true, label: false, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length) %>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label style="font-weight: bold">Confirm Your Password</label>

              <div class="form-control">
                <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true, label: false %>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-actions">
              <%= f.submit 'Sign up', class: 'btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block' %>
            </div>
          </div>
      <% end %>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Routes.rb

```
devise_for :users
  get 'welcome/home', :as => 'home'
  get 'welcome/about', :as => 'about'
  get 'welcome/contact', :as => 'contact'
  get 'welcome/help', :as => 'help'
  get 'welcome/blog', :as => 'blog'
  get 'welcome/privacy', :as => 'privacy'
  get 'welcome/media', :as => 'media'
  get 'welcome/developers', :as => 'developers'
  #get ':id' => 'users#show', :as => :user_profile
  get 'subscription/show'
  get 'subscription/new'
  get 'subscription/create'
  get 'subscription/destroy'
  get 'hub/index'
  #get ':id/setting' => 'users#edit', :as => :user_setting
  #match ':id/setting' => 'users#update', via: [:put, :patch]
  root 'welcome#home'
  resource :subscription
  resources :posts, :only => [:index, :create, :show, :new ]
  resources :posts do
    put 'like', to: 'link#upvote'
    put 'dislike', to: 'link#downvote'
  end

  resources :users do
    member do
      get :follow
      get :unfollow
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can I see the stack trace from the terminal and insert it into your post?

Comment: I have devise_for :users near the very top of my routing file.

Comment: cAn u check your routes, I feel some validation on your attributes are failing

Comment: I added the routes that I currently have.

Comment: Your form is sending  `GET "/users/sign_up..."` with the params url-encoded. This will always just render the form.
 You form should be sending a POST request which goes to `Devise::RegistrationsController#create`. I don't remember the exact routes generated by devise off the top of my head but you can get a list by running `rake routes | grep devise`

Comment: Aside from that you got some real issues. `get ':id' => 'users#show', :as => :user_profile` is an exceptionally greedy route which will swallow any route such as `/foo` and `/bar`. Don't skimp on REST just to get short URLs. Use `/users/:id` instead. The fact that you have to add a bunch of weird hacks to your ApplicationController for `current_user` etc. indicates that you might have messed something up when setting up Devise.

Comment: I removed the super methods from my application_controller.rb. The reason I did that was because Rubymine 8 struggles with caching devise methods. So, it complains that no method exist. It seems like the profile related routes are causing some issues with devise. I may have to combine everything related to the user's profile with the devise.

Comment: In the routes file, I see `devise_for :users` and `resources :users`.. Is your server responding to a HTTP POST request to create users? All I see right now, is your server is getting authenticity tokens but is not returning some form of POST request. You also should probably want to use `devise_scope :users do` block.

Comment: I copied over the logic to a new project. Now, Devise is working and I refactored my code. The structure is much neater and the problems are no longer occurring. Also, I lowered the version of Ruby on Rails, just in case it was a compatibility issue of some sorts.